# VW Golf MK4 1.4 16v 1998 - Steering wheel hard to turn after Power Steering Rack change

Tags: vw, power-steering, golf, steering-wheel, pump

Sorry for my English,

I had a problem with my power steering rack that had some fluid leaks and some noise when the fluid level was down. I never used the car without fluid.
Except the steering noise and the oil leak, the steering wheel was easy to move.

I brought the car to the mechanic yesterday and he changed the **steering rack**, but now the steering wheel is very hard to move mostly when the car is stopped.

The mechanic told me that maybe the new rack needs 2 - 3 days and it will be better. If it doesn't improve then it will be necessary to change the **Power Steering Pump** but he doesn't look so sure that it will fix the problem and I was thinking that with the old rack the power steering pump was OK. This is my first car and I am already hating it because I spent a lot of money repairing it.

Except for burning this car, does somebody have an idea or suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some steering racks come with plugs in them which, if not removed during installation, can cause exactly what you are talking about. If the power steering pump is making a lot of noise, this might be the issue. If the power steering pump is making a lot of noise, it could just be the pump, though. I take it the steering wheel wasn't hard to turn *before* the rack was replaced? Was the system properly bled?

Comment: Do you still hear the noise when you try and turn the steering wheel or is that gone now?

Comment: No, there is no noise when i turn the steering wheel. Its just hard to turn. After i asked the question here i used my car in the highway at 110km/h about 70mph and it looks that the steering wheel is easy to turn just for a short range, and if I want to turn it more at that speed it's still hard to turn.

Comment: Is the steering wheel any easier to turn when the car is stationary but running compared to when stationary with the ignition off?  Also, do me a favor, please don't take the car out on the highway again until this is resolved.

Comment: The steering wheel is the same when is the car is on or off.

Comment: Did enough fluid get put into the system after the rack was changed?

Comment: I don't believe avoiding highways is necessary if the steering rack was just replaced and the mechanic didn't attempt to repair the old rack. The power steering system is quite foolproof: either it gives boost or it doesn't. It is extremely rare that it would randomly start to steer to the left or to the right. At high speeds, you can turn the wheel quite easily without needing boost. The trouble is that turning the wheel when stationary is hard if there's no boost.

Answer (score 0):

That a new rack or rebuilt . either way it's either been tighten way to much if it's s remanufactured or if it's used it's just no good .you should have been able to turn it all way right then all way left once or twice that should have bleed air out .must are self bleeding like that anyway and after should have been able to turn with two finger's.if your pump turned other rack sure should turned that one. I would change it back to other one one that pulls either way inner tie rod ins out of adjustment or wore out Just my opinion but have been in a few rebuilds on them  .good luck hope you get it straightened out.